# Building a touch first desktop (non-metro) application for WIndows 8

Tags: touch, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm currently in the early design phase for a lob application I'm going to be making for my company which is targeted for Windows 8 tablets. It won't meet the standards for a metro app (will be using SQL Server and other reasons) but I like the look and feel of metro apps since they're touch first designed. Are the Microsoft supplied templates/controls/themes able to be used with a desktop app?

Comment: What is the exact question? You want to use windows 8 styles in a desktop WPF application?

Comment: Yes, basically can you easily create a metro style app but target the desktop? For example, can we use the same controls that are employed by metro apps?

Comment: I saw an opensource porject which port WP7 style xaml files to WPF, but it sucks.

Comment: Try to use the styles from this file: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Light-and-Dark-Theme-Xaml-eca02f2b/sourcecode?fileId=44760&pathId=248431445. I didn't tried to use them, but it is exactly those styles which are used in metro applications.

Answer (score 0):

Metro project templates will not work as desktop apps. Metro apps rely on Win RT and Desktop apps rely on Win32 or .Net. The [Windows 8 platform](http://media.infragistics.com/community/general/windows8-platform-tools.jpg) image shows the clear distinction in targets. 
There is no implementation of metro style controls for desktop in Developer Preview.

Comment: It is possible to access a very small subset of Metro APIs from desktop apps but this is an exception to the rule.UI Controls are not part of this subset. So, you cannot use Metro UI controls in a desktop App.  Check [Windows Developer Preview Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh405364(v=VS.85).aspx) and [What's New in the .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx#tailored)

Comment: @Cody C, "Neither of those links support your statement", really ? WinRT has hundrends of areas in [Windows Developer Preview Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh405364(v=VS.85).aspx) you only see a list of 14 and none of them are UI controls. Getting back to the original question "Are the Microsoft supplied templates/controls/themes able to be used with a desktop app?", the answer is no, and it is validated by looked at that link isn't it !?